Shared cloud disk for data between multiple VMs running postgres for cold replication
I want to create a database which most of the time will be mostly idle. However, it is going to have geospatial data and I think, at times, it'll be processor and memory taxed because of geographic joins and/or providing MVTs.
One idea I had was to have a smallish VM with the main postgres installation and its data directory would be a shared disk where the main has read/write and then there'd be cold (off most of the time) VMs which would read directly from the shared data disk as read-only. Somewhere in there I'd have to have pg_bouncer or similar to manage the connections between main and replicants and some logic to actually spin up those standby VMs but set that aside for the moment.
My question is, can Postgres handle having a strictly read-only data directory such that this could, at least in principle, work?
